# Flutter Build Failed with an Exception Build file 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\connectivity_plus-5.0.2\android\build.gradle'

Tags: android, flutter

I'm fairly new to flutter and I'm trying to import a practice project for me to work on. The problem is I can't run it and instead encounter this build exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\connectivity_plus-5.0.2\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':connectivity_plus'.
> Could not find method namespace() for arguments [dev.fluttercommunity.plus.connectivity] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

It was a mess earlier and I already did 'Pub get' as well as updated all the outdated dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Run in project path terminal

```
 flutter clean
```

then change the version of connectivity_plus

```
flutter build apk
```